# Can´t change UICollectionView Size of UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I am wondering if it is possible to change the CollectionView Contentsize on the Storyboard, when using UICollectionViewController. I can´t change the size, it is fixed. I would like to add a Tab navigation, but this is not possible, since UICollectionView cant be resized on the Storyboard.
How can I do this?

I also tried to use UIViewController and put the delegates into the header < ... >, seems to have troubles. I would be thankful for help.
Thank you very much.!

[Cant Edit Width Height of UICollectionView inside of UICollectionViewController Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxG44.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes...the size can't be changed when using a UICollectionViewController. You must add a UICollectionView to an UIViewController. Then you can change the collection view's size.