# Differences between view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

Hi I'm new to Xcode and don't quite understand the difference between all the view controllers. Eg what is the difference between a uiviewcontroller with a collection view on it and a uicollectionview controller it self? Confused as to why I wouldn't use a view controller then add views onto it depending on my requirements eh table, collection etc. Can anyone help to shed some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's based on your requirements. You may change some properties with your View controllers. But when you use as part of its' controllers, you can't change it.

> For example you Can´t change UICollectionView Size of UICollectionViewController(see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970896/cant-change-uicollectionview-size-of-uicollectionviewcontroller)).

In these case, you must use `UICollectionView` in viewcontroller. As like this, if you want to customize some property but functionality are same in all.

Here I mention some ref for you: [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626495/how-do-i-hook-up-uicollectionviewcontroller-in-uicontainerview)

Comment: It means if i want to have one View with two controls inside it like i want to add a tab bar at the bottom and collection view above, so i should use UIViewController instead of using UICollectionViewController ? because i can't change `UICollectionView` size, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can take `UICollectionViewController` as a template which will have every thing for you. And view controller is simple scracth pad, you have to add things on it. There are some pros and cons in `view controller` you have to do every thing yourself, but `collectioViewController` you got controller with `collectionView`. But you can not change things as easily in it.